# Is x a reserved keyword in Javascript FF/Safari not in IE?

Tags: javascript, reserved-words

A web page of a web application was showing a strange error. I regressively removed all the HTML/CSS/JS code and arrived to the basic and simple code below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html><head>
<title>test</title>

   <script type="text/javascript">
      var TestObj =
      {
         foo: function() {}
      }

      alert(x); //ok displays "undefined"
      var x = TestObj.foo;
      var z = TestObj.foo;
    </script>

</head><body>

   <p onclick='alert(x);'>Click shows function foo!</p>
   <img onclick='alert(x);' alt='CRAZY click displays a number in FF/Safari not function foo' src='' style='display: block; width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 1px solid #00ff00;'>
   <p onclick='alert(x);'>Click shows function foo!</p>

</body></html>
```

It's crazy: when clicking on P elements the string "function(){}" is displaied as expected. But **when clicking on IMG element it shows a number as if x function got in some way removed from memory or deinstantiated** (it does not even show x as "undefined" but as a number).

To let you test it quickly I placed the working test above also [here](http://vanylla.com/crazy/test.html).

This can be reproduced on both **Firefox 3.6 and Safari 4.0.4**.

Everything **works properly only on IE7+**.

I'm really clueless, I was wondering if **x** is maybe a reserved keyword in JS Firefox/Safari. Thanks to anyone who could help!

FYI:

1. if you repalce x() with z()
   everything work prefectly in all
   browsers (this is even more crazy to
   me)
2. adding a real image in src
   attribute does not fix the problem
3. removing style in img does not fix
   the problem (i gave style to image
   only to help you clicking on image
   thus you can see the imnage border)

Comment: Don't think `x` is reserved; I've used it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is with variable scope, not that "x" is reserved.  An image object has a property named "x".  You can see this with Chrome's developer tools.  When you call "alert(x);" on the image object, the "x" in scope is the "x" property on the image.

Comment: The `x` property seems to be the x-coordinate of the image; `y` is what you would expect, too.

Comment: Ah yes, beat me too it.  This is what I was thinking too.  But I haven't been able to find any official documentation of this behavior.  Presumably the functionality is just left over from the "DOM 0" days?

Comment: @David: if I was an artist I would build a statue to you and to stackoverflow. I really, really appreciated your help, I was nearly beating my head on the desk today! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just to complete the answers from [David](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2495061/is-x-a-reserved-keyword-in-javascript-ff-safari-not-in-ie/2495091#2495091) and [Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2495061/is-x-a-reserved-keyword-in-javascript-ff-safari-not-in-ie/2495098#2495098), this behavior is not documented at all, but it work like the following in almost every modern browser:

The content of an inline event handler becomes the `FunctionBody` of a function that the browser calls when it fires that event.

The scope chain of this function is *augmeted* with the element, the element's `FORM` (if it exits and is a `FORM` element), and `document` itself.

It looks something like this in code:

```
function onclick(event) {
  with(document) {
    with(this.form) {
      with(this) {
        // inline event handler content...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This behavior can cause all sort of *name conflicts* due the augmentation of the scope chain you cannot be 100% sure about what you are referring, it could be an attribute of the element itself, an attribute of the element's form, an attribute of the `document` object or any global variable.

Recommended article:

- [Unsafe Names for HTML Form Controls](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/names/event_handler.html)

Answer (score 1):

I can't seem to find any documentation to support this, but my guess is that the `<img>` tag is being treated specially, and the object is actually a JavaScript `Image` object, not a normal DOM element.  The `Image` object has an `x` property, and so your unscoped reference to `x` means `Image.x`.  If you want the global `x` property, just use `window.x` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Still supported by some browsers, before the dom spec, images, a elements and area elements all had read only x and y properties for their coordinates on the page.